# subprocess.Popen() - does order matter for p.stdout.read() and p.wait()?

Tags: python, subprocess

Questions about Python's subprocess.Popen() objects
(Please assume a scenario where the number of bytes being generated for stdout/stderr does not fill up the OS pipe buffers and create a deadlock waiting for the OS pipe buffers to accept more data)

1) Does it matter what order p.stdout.read() and p.wait() are in?

2) Does read() on a stdout/stderr subprocess.PIPE block until the process has terminated?

3) Are the stdout/stderr subprocess.PIPE file objects and data available even after the process has terminated?

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(args="ls", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout = process.stdout.read()
# Does the above read() block until the process has terminated?
stderr = process.stderr.read()
return_code = process.wait()

process = subprocess.Popen(args="ls", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
return_code = process.wait() 
# Are stdout and stderr pipes available now, even after the process terminated?
stdout = process.stdout.read()
stderr = process.stderr.read()
```

Comment: If all you're doing is reading output, I'd highly recommend `.communicate()` rather than `.read()`+`.wait()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: Does it matter what order p.stdout.read() and p.wait() are in?
A: No.

Q: Does read() on a stdout/stderr subprocess.PIPE block until the process has terminated?
A: If no limit on the number of bytes to read is specified, then it will block until the stream is closed (which is likely when the process terminates).

Q: Are the stdout/stderr subprocess.PIPE file objects and data available even after the process has terminated?
A: Yes.

You may want to pay special attention to this warning from the `subprocess` documentation:

> Warning: This will deadlock when using `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use `communicate()` to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks Amber.  I was aware of the deadlock warning, but was assuming a scenario where the stdout/stderr data is small (e.g., < 1k each). I've now edited the question to reflect that assumption. 

Your #2 and #3 answers are clear.  For #1, could you clarify in light of my assumption?

Comment: In that case, it shouldn't matter - neither call should block longer than the other would.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a library like [`sarge`](http://sarge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#capturing-stdout-and-stderr-from-commandshttp://sarge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#capturing-stdout-and-stderr-from-commands) which allows flexibility when doing I/O with subprocesses. (Disclosure: I'm the maintainer. I wrote it partly in response to the kind of difficulties you're having.)